# How does the resitivity of different material add up?

Tags: resistance, materials

I have material A (e.g. carbon) which is a poor conductor with a resistance of around 700 ohm. what would happen if I melted some high conductive material (B) on it (e.g. copper).

Would the resistance of the combined product be the summation of both resistance or ould be a value less than material A?

Comment: It depends on where and how you connect the electrodes and the exact pour of copper over the carbon. There are probably as many variations as there are grains of sand in the Sahara.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @winny, not HW. I was just wondering!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends where you added this extra material.

Base material:

[image]

Copper added all over the top: appears as a parallel resistor

[image]

Copper added on the ends: appears as series resistance

[image]

A strip of copper?  appears as parallel resistance

[image]

A blob? series-parallel

[image]

Comment: Good, quick and simple answer. What more is there to add +1

Comment: You should address that to the guy making the answer.

Comment: @JonRB Does the resistor in the last scenario refer to the low or the high resistance material? Also, for Copper added all over the top, it is okay if it is copper strips with mm distance from each other?

Comment: @AnwarElhadad I purposefully did not label the resistors as the specific resistance will vary. I have updated the images and labeled which is COPPER and which is CARBON.  What needs to be clear is for different configurations each resistance may have a different value as you start stacking up their cross-sectional area, length and rho.   As to the question of copper in strips, that is the same as one large copper, a strip

Comment: Erm the last image has the end resistors labelled copper still from the first image, but they should say carbon.